# Can node running locally require a file from inside a docker container?

Tags: node.js, docker

I think the title really says it all but just to clarify, say I'm running node like so on my macbook:

```
node file1.js
```

```
//file1.js
require("some/secret/path/to/a/file/in/a/docker/container")
```

is that possible?

If so I'd love to know what that secret path might be. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no absolute path that I am aware of, that gets access to your container, but you have some options:

You can run your container with a binded volume, to gain access to basically a shared folder.

For example, in your host machine you can make a folder:

```
mkdir /home/user/shared_folder
```

Then, run your container binding that folder:

```
docker run -v /home/user/shared_folder:/some_path/in/your/container some_image
```

Anytime your container modifies this folder, adds something in, deletes something, your host machine will be able to see those changes as well.

Your other option is to use docker cp and copy the files that you need, from your container to your host.

You can do this using child_process's.

```
  var exec = require('child_process').exec;

    exec("docker cp container_id:/some_text host_path")
```